Webpack 5 splitChunks.chunks = "all" causes modules not to load
I am trying to set up webpack to build my source code into its own output bundle, and output all node_modules to their own separate vendor file(s).  I am using webpack-bundle-analyzer to see what's happening.  Without an optimization property, I get this kind of output:
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot", "js", "index.js"),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot", "dist"),
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        chunkFilename: "[name].bundle.js",
    },
    cache: {
        type: "filesystem",
        allowCollectingMemory: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [...],
    },
};

Gives this output:

You can see the main.bundle.js includes all my src files (in wwwroot/js), but it also includes a bunch of code from node_modules, and it blows up the size to 6MB.  This is not what I want - main.bundle.js should include only my source code.  In this case, main.bundle.js looks like this at a glance:

However, it does work, i.e. the webpage loads with <script src="~/dist/main.bundle.js"></script>, all the associated modules are pulled in, and everything functions.
Using optimization and chunks: all
Using some optimization, I can get the bundle to ouput the main.bundle.js with only my source code packed into it, and all the node_modules separate:
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
    // ... identical to above, plus:
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: "all",
            maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
            minSize: 0,
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true,
                    name(module) {
                        return module
                            .identifier()
                            .split("node_modules")
                            .reduceRight((item) => item)
                            .replace(".js", "");
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
};

The use of chunks: all, maxInitialRequests: Infinity, minSize: 0 is what does just the trick to get me my desired output: my source code only within main.bundle.js, and the node_modules packaged up separately.  (That idea came from this question):

My main.bundle.js here is about 500kb, and a quick glimpse of it looks like this:

The problem is, this doesn't work.  The webpack loads, and pulls in main.bundle.js, but  it doesn't seem to ever run.  I.e. throwing a console.log('find me') into my entry of index.js makes it into the main.bundle.js, but that code is never executed, even though the script is pulled into the page.
The critical piece seems to be chunks: all - when I use this, the bundle is split nicely as shown in the second image above, but the code never runs.  When I don't use this, the code is not split nicely between source code and node_modules, but the code does run (regardless of minSize or maxInitialRequests.
For good measure I tried chunks: initial, and while the organization of node modules is a bit different, the result is the same - nice small main.bundle.js, that doesn't actually run:

What am I doing wrong that chunks: "all" / "initial" causes the main bundle to be pulled into the page, but never run?
